# How can I prevent stretching an image using html5 picture tag and a defined height?

Tags: html, css, image

I'm using HTML5's `<picture>` tags to create a responsive header that will stretch the entire width of the browser. The header uses an image as the background.

For larger screens I limited the height to a defined value. However, I noticed that a certain breakpoint the image starts to stretch and distort the image.

I'm familiar with using CSS's `background-image: url();` to create a mask in order to prevent the distortion, but I don't know what best practices are with `<picture>`.

My code currently stretches and distorts the image. Is there a way to 'mask' the image?

Comment: Not sure of any "mask" that prevents stretching. Usually this happens when the image is being sized at an incorrect aspect ratio. There is the css `object-fit` property which might help you here. you can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

Comment: After looking at the link, it seems applying `object-fit: cover` to the fallback `<img>` tag does exactly what I need it to do. Thank you, I really appreciate it!

Comment: For background, you have background-size  +background-position  and for img you have object-fit  + object-position , the result/option are similar . See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size  https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User zgood was able to lead me in the right direction. Adding `object-fit: cover` to the `<picture>`'s `<img>` tag got the job done.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you should know is that if you will give height to any image then in some screens it will stretch.

So instead of giving the height you should take the image of exact size it will do the thing.

If you can share the code I can fix it and send it to you.

Hope it helps.